# SQL COUNT(*) returning the wrong answer

Tags: sql

The following script should return the name of the departments and the number of employees that are in those departments, the Marketing,Executive and Sales departments have '0' employees but instead of '0' , the returned value is '1'. How can I correct it?

```
select Department, Departments.DepartmentID, count(*) as 'NumOfEmps' 
from Departments
left join Employees
on   Employees.DepartmentID = Departments.DepartmentID
group by Departments.DepartmentID,Department
```

[image]

Comment: It's returning 1 because you're using a left join, which of course will return a row if there is a record in the Departments table, even if there is none in the Employees table.  (@Yuck posted what was *going to be* the rest of my answer.  Since he beat me to it, I'll just leave this comment to explain why you're getting a count of 1 in your results where you expect 0.)

Comment: @DavidStratton if only `COUNT` accepted something other than `*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `Count(*)` count the thing you want to count  namely the employees.

`Count(*)` counts the whole row. Since there's always going to be at least one record for each Department in Departments when you do count(*) you'll always get at least 1

```
SELECT d.Department, d.DepartmentID, count(e.EmployeeID)
FROM Departments d
    LEFT JOIN employees e
    ON d.DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID
GROUP BY 
 d.Department, d.DepartmentID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c0cf/2)

Comment: Nice one, short and with a Demo too, also in SQLFiddle which I never knew existed!!!

Comment: Yeah SQLFiddle's awesome. It was built by [Jake Feasel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel)

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that all in one query.  You need a sub-query to get the employee counts first, then get the related department information (name, etc.) using the aggregated results:

```
SELECT Department, Departments.DepartmentID, t.NumOfEmps
FROM Departments
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DepartmentID, count(*) as 'NumOfEmps'
           FROM Employees
           GROUP BY DepartmentID) t
  ON t.DepartmentID = Departments.DepartmentID
```

I'm making some assumptions about your schema since it's not listed. Column names may be off a bit, but this is the general idea.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm?  You can get the employee count without using a sub-query - all the original query needs is swapping `count(*)` with `count(Employees.id)`

Comment: @SamDufel Force of habit, I suppose. Usually queries of this sort are more involved so when I see it pop up my approach is the first that comes to mind. Nice catch though!

Comment: @ConradFrix Fixed, that was a copy / paste typo.