# How to bulid a report with a total and breakout columns with SQL Server and Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a data structure where I have two tables Alpha and Beta and they are one to many. For the sake of an example let's say that table alpha has a column for "State" and table B has "Colors you like" and you can pick more than one. I would like to build a report that has columns like this:

```
STATE          TOTAL     RED     GREEN     BLUE
Alaska         5         1       3         1
Florida        2         2       2         0
New York       10        5       8         1
```

The column TOTAL would be a count of the records in Alpha and as you can see due to the one to many relationship the sum of the colors can exceed the count. I suppose it could be less as well if people didn't like colors.

How would you build a report like this. I'll be using SQL Server and Reporting Services in .NET so it could either be a complex query that I just dump into a data table report or a less complex query with some counting and totaling done by the report. I just don't really know the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Are the colors known and design time? The answer to the question impacts possible solutions.

Comment: No and they can change after deployment. The colors are actually user configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know which colors are going to be the columns you should use the [Matrix Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

You'll need to set up the query

```
SELECT 
    a.State,
    b.ColorName,
    COUNT(b.ColorID) ColorCount
FROM
    alpha a
    LEFT JOIN beta b
    ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY 
    a.State,
    b.ColorName
```

Just drag state for the rows, color for the columns and ColorCount for the data (`Count(ColorID)` will display in the data field))

Note: The `LEFT JOIN` and Count(ColorID) instead of Count(*) are required if you want a `0` value to appear correctly.

If you did know the colors you could use `PIVOT` or the sum case technique

`SELECT state SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Red, ...`

Comment: How would the query for this method work? I would just select Alpha and inner join Beta?

Comment: @William since you asked actually no it needs to be a LEFT JOIN since you're expecting zeros. See [SQL COUNT(*) returning the wrong answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10540763/119477)

Comment: I see. I'll take a swing at that when I am working on the project again. Thank you for your response.